# c# winforms скрыть кнопки по условию

Tags: c#

winforms, при заходе в приложению через формы авторизации пытаюсь пользователям ограничить доступ к функционалам приложения с помощью button.Visible или же button.Enabled, при первом переходе в первую форму скрывает кнопки. Если перейти дальше по форме никаких действий не происходит, тоесть условия выполняется только для первой формы. пробовал, вызвал метод условий в других формах - не работает. как заставить работать условия авторизации на всех формах ?

```
 public partial class Login : Form
{
  
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
   
    MySqlConnection con = ConDatabase.GetDBConnection();
    Form1 fm1 = new Form1();
    Sum sum = new Sum();
    private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    
        SelectSatsFromSum();
           DostupUslowiyya();
      
    }

    private void LoginTextbox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (LoginTextbox.Text == "")
        {
            LoginTextbox.Text = "Login";
            LoginTextbox.ForeColor = Color.Silver;
        }
    }
    private void LoginTextbox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (LoginTextbox.Text == "Login")
            LoginTextbox.Text = "";
        LoginTextbox.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
    
  public void DostupUslowiyya()
    {
    //  Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue);
        MySqlCommand commandSelect = new MySqlCommand("Select COUNT(*) from login JOIN status ON login.status_id = status.id where login=@login AND parol=@parol AND status.name = @status", con);
        commandSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", LoginTextbox.Text);
        commandSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parol", textBox2.Text);
        commandSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", comboBox1.Text);
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(commandSelect);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1" && comboBox1.Text == "admin" )
        {
            this.Hide();
           
            sum.Show();
           
        }
        else if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1" && comboBox1.Text == "user")
        {

            this.Hide();
           
            sum.Show();
            fm1.Addbutton.Visible = false;
            fm1.Deletebutton.Visible = false;
        }
        else if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1" && comboBox1.Text == "user1")
        {

            this.Hide();
            
            sum.Show();
            fm1.Addbutton.Visible = false;
            fm1.Deletebutton.Visible = false;
            fm1.AddDslambutton.Visible = false;
            fm1.Updatebutton.Visible = false;
        }
    } 
      
    void SelectSatsFromSum()
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter adapterr = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT name FROM status", con);
        DataSet dsett = new DataSet();
        adapterr.Fill(dsett);
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "name";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
        comboBox1.DataSource = dsett.Tables[0];
        comboBox1.Text = "Status";
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
      DostupUslowiyya();

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //   SelectSatsFromSum();
    }

}
```

Comment: я честно и долго вчитывался в вопрос. Пытался понять, что нужно сделать. Впечатление такое, что проблема у вас какая то очень простая, но понять её я не могу.  > Если перейти дальше по форме никаких действий не происходит - а что должно происходить? и что значит "пройти дальше по форме"? Может, вы добавите картинку, чтобы понять, о чем идёт речь?

Comment: А, я понял. Вы хотите сделать форму авторизации! Типа, нажал логин-пароль, они проверились, если правильные - то открывается следующая форма! так?

Comment: @S.H. почти ,  допустим у меня 4 формы , пользователь авторизуется через форму попадает в определенную форму,  при авторизаций пользователь выбирает какие у него права - обычный пользователь , админ,  или ответственный работник грубо говоря , вот выбирал обычного пользователя - у него должны быть ограничения на всех 4-х формах. тоесть кнопка добавления удаления или же обновления

Comment: Очень хорошо, что вы пояснили этот момент, т.к. я тоже по описанию задачи не очень понял её сути. Можете попробовать программно создавать нужные кнопки, исходя из прав пользователя. Тогда не будет проблемы с необходимостью скрывать или выключать кнопки. Как вариант, можете создать базовый класс CreateButton, через конструктор которого вы будете как раз таки создавать эти кнопки. Это должно уменьшить количество кода и устранить проблему с его повтором.

Comment: @Frehzy, ваша идея насчет базового класса кнопки очень заманчиво,  этот класс нужно будет указать в условиях при авторизации? или еще нужно вызывать в формах ?  и еще такой момент в моем примере коде нельзя ли унаследовать метод условия проверки другим формам ? допустим во всех формах по умолчанию `button.Visible = false` .  а по условию доступа сделать true

Comment: Есть несколько вариантов реализации. Самый, как по мне, простой - передавать List<Button> в качестве параметра (в конструктор) при создании экземпляра формы, которая открывается после авторизации. Далее, допустим, в TableLayoutPanel добавляем все кнопки с помощью "buttons.ForEach(x => TableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(x));". Создавать собственно сами кнопки мы будем ещё на форме авторизации. Касаемо базового класса - нужно подумать, какие поля должны быть у данной кнопки, и что она должна делать. Если вам нужен только ивент клика, то может можно и без базового класса обойтись

Comment: Как по мне, писать для каждой кнопки Visible = false и что-то подобное - не совсем правильно. Зачем форме иметь кнопки, которые на ней даже не отображаются? А так, если вы хотите быстро изменить для всех кнопок какое-то значение в форме, то удобнее будет воспользоваться "this.Controls.OfType<Button>().Select(x => x.Visible = false)". Не тестировал, но должно работать

Comment: спасибо ! попробую , должен работать !

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134578/discussion-between-mister-junior-and-frehzy).